# Make Docky Timer play a sound?

Tags: sound, docky

is there a way to make the Docky Timer Docklet play an alarm sound, after a timer has run out?

At the moment there only seems to be visual feedback, so you need to watch the screen to know, whether time has run out or not.

Thanks
YSN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Docky 2.1 or later, there should be a sound notification when the timer expires. The version in the Maverick repositories is 2.0, so you will need to install Docky from the [Development PPA](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa) for this feature.

Also, make sure you have system sounds enabled: *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Sound* and select the *Ubuntu* theme.

[image]